# How to reset button color on Second click ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have a `button` which highlights on **first** click. On **second** click it should reset back to the same color. I am using a `boolean` `isSelected` to determine whether its highlighted or not. The button is being highlighted but somehow its not resetting back to its original color. Any help would be appreciated.

I am decalring isSelected as `private bool isSelected = false;`

**Button Event Handler**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isSelected)
        {
            isSelected = true;
            Styles.buttonHighlight(Button2);
        }
        else
        {
            isSelected = false;
            Styles.buttonReset(Button2);
        }
    }
```

**Styling Methods**

```
public static void buttonHighlight(Button button)
    {
        button.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        button.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    public static void buttonReset(Button button)
    {
        button.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ffffff");
        button.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#848484");
    }
```

Comment: Where is 'isSelected' stored?

Comment: @SystemDown its declared outside the event handler

Comment: I would toggle a css class using javascript.  But that's just me :)

Comment: are you wanting a double click..? or a single click.. this should work for you `button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to save a state of a variable between postbacks... This isn't as simple as you think...
In your case, you're setting `IsSelected = true` yet on the next Postback (next time the button is clicked) it's back to false since the variable is re Declared  on every postback (to it's original `false` value in this case). Asp.Net is basically Stateless.

You could solve this by saving the IsSelected in the **[Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** or **[ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)** or even as a *hiddenfield*...

I think ViewState should be adequate to your needs...

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool selected = false;

    if (ViewState["IsSelected"] != null)
    {
       selected = (bool) ViewState["IsSelected"];
    }

    if (!selected)
    {
        ViewState["IsSelected"] = true;
        Styles.buttonHighlight(Button2);
    }
    else
    {
        ViewState["IsSelected"] = false;
        Styles.buttonReset(Button2);
    }
}
```

Using the Session is quite the same, just change `ViewState` to `Session` in the above code. You should read a little about the difference between them (I added links) and see which best matches your needs.

Comment: @Blachsma if I include it under AJAX `updatePanel`, do I still have to store it in session variables?

Comment: An UpdatePanel doesn't really make a change for the Session variables. It *can* have an affect if you save it in a hiddenfield for instance (which is outside the updatepanel)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem: `isSelected` will always be false.

The thing you have to remember about ASP.NET (and web apps in general) is that everything is stateless. Which basically means that a *new* instance of the page class is created for each postback. And since `isSelected` is a variable within this class, it too will be instantiated again and its previous values will not be stored.

So how do you get around this? You store the value of `isSelected` somewhere. You can use Session variables (which are stored in server memory), or preferably ViewState variables (which are stored in the page text itself). You could make `isSelected` into a property with a getter and setter like this:

```
private bool isSelected
{
    get 
    {
        if(ViewState["isSelected"] != null && ViewState["isSelected"] is bool)
            return (bool)ViewState["isSelected"];
        else
            return false;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["isSelected"] = value;
    }

}
```

Using a ViewState would require that ViewState be turned on, which it is by default. Another possibility is to store the contents of `isSelected` inside a Hidden Field control (which uses ViewState in the background as well).

Comment: thanks! but I had to accept Blachshma becaz he answered earlier

Comment: @DarknessBeginsHere - No problem. Glad we could get your problem solved.